# iTunes sync apps failed to install using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have created an .ipa file using Phonegap. For testing I uploaded the developer certificates and device UDID. Its working fine. Now, I want to distribute this apps using Application Loader. For this I uploaded the apple distributor certificate and distribute mobile provision file on the phonegap cloud and generated the .ipa file. When I tried this apps with iPhone 6.3.1, its giving me error: **iTunes sync apps failed to install**
Please help me to get out of this problem..

Comment: see wheather this helps http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146301/itunes-sync-failed-install-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to submit the app (you mentioned Application Loader which is used for submitting apps) or install it on devices for testing? I am assuming you are trying to install it on devices for testing.

If the app fails to install, check for one of these

1. The mobileprovision you are using has your device's UDID. Test apps can only be installed on devices whose UDID is included in the mobileprovision (unless you are distributing for enterprises)
2. The mobileprovision is installed on your device (try using a service like Testflight - you'll know whether your device has the necessary setup)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Actually I am trying to submit the apps.

Comment: In that case you won't be able to install the app on your device. For installing apps through iTunes, they must be signed with a developer mobileprovision or an adhoc mobileprovision.

Comment: okk..if I publish the app using xCode in release mode, would it be work perfectly ??

Comment: Make sure you test it out on a device. Don't rely on testing on a simulator.

Comment: One more thing, once I uploaded the .ipa file, can I update it later?